# Поиск идентификатора объекта по имеющемуся тегу

Tags: java, android

У меня есть метод, где я изменяю картинку на странице сверяя имя с переменной `heroNameInPage`, которое мне уже известно.

```
private void setImage() {
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageHero);
    switch (heroNameInPage) {
        case "Bar": img.setImageResource(R.drawable.Bar); break;
        case "Asmon": img.setImageResource(R.drawable.Asmon);break;}}
```

Таких case планируется несколько сотен или тысяча, поэтому я хочу оптимизировать код.
На объектах ImageView, которые расположены на других страницах, у меня прописан тег на каждый ImageView. 
Как мне вытаскивая тег и сверяя его с `heroNameInPage` изменять ресурс для img???
Есть примерно такой шаблон:

```
    ImageView item;
    for (int idF = 0; idF < 99999999; idF++){
        item = findViewById(R.id.idF);
        if (heroNameInPage.equals(item.getTag().toString())){
            img.setImageResource(item.getImageResource);
        }
```

Comment: item = findViewById(R.id.idF) - это работает?

Comment: К сожалению нет) Не знаю как среди объектов искать по айди

Comment: Шаблон в виде псевдокода

Comment: Может быть каким-то образом через Assets?

Comment: Да можно то по-разному, но не понятно что Вы пытаетесь сделать - поясните более развёрнуто. И что есть разные страницы - это разные Activity? Самое простое - это параллельно складывать в `Map` с тегами в качестве ключей или лучше в `LruCache`, чтобы понизить шансы влететь в ООМ.

Comment: Да, разные страницы = разные Activity. Насчет развернуто, какая часть вам непонятна? Мне надо менять изображение в моем ImageView. Изображений сотни и тысячи. "Самое простое - это параллельно складывать в Map с тегами в качестве ключей или лучше в LruCache, чтобы понизить шансы влететь в ООМ." Можете пожалуйста дать ссылки с примерами?